# Android Material Raised button style and shadow

Tags: android, button, android-5.0-lollipop

How can one implement a Material Raised button. I see a lot of styles out there but is there a standard for the style and shadow. Please if someone can chime in about this with the appropriate xml.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is set the [elevation](http://www.google.com/design/spec/what-is-material/elevation-shadows.html#elevation-shadows-elevation-android-) of different states. Or if you just want a regular "raised" state, you can set the elevation in your style or on the button itself.

Note that this is only valid for Lollipop devices as elevation only works on SDK 21 or higher.

Comment: What about the shadow on the button?

Comment: Elevation will create the shadow on Lollipop and higher.